# Search form_tag not working Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, search, model-view-controller

I am really stuck... it seems to be simple but I am really missing something here...
So, I am building like a product show page. I want to make a form field that returns the user's State when input zipcode.

This is my form, it is the show.html.erb. I want the information to appear also in this view:

```
<%= form_tag product_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :cep,
     params[:cep],
     class: "form-control mr-2",
     placeholder: "13087560",
     maxlength: 8
  %>
  <%= submit_tag "find", class: "btn-flat my-3 my-0" %>
<% end %>

<p class="product-data"><%= @uf %></p>
```

This is my controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

require 'open-uri'

  def index
    if params[:query]
      @products = Product.search(params[:query])
    else
      @products = Product.all
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def uf_search
    if params[:cep]
      @uf = JSON.parse(open("https://viacep.com.br/ws/#{params[:cep]}/json/").read)
      @uf = @uf['uf']
      @uf
    end
  end
end
```

It's not giving me any errors, but the information just don't show on the view... and the @uf value is nil.

Comment: There is no problem here. I think there's a problem with the form url. I guess the request is not going to uf_search action. Check the form url and routes.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

people!

Actually the problem was in the controller... I did this and it worked as I expected:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

require 'open-uri'

  def index
    if params[:query]
      @products = Product.search(params[:query])
    else
      @products = Product.all
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    uf_search # inserting the uf_search here solved it
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def uf_search
    if params[:cep]
      url = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/#{params[:cep]}/json/"
      address = JSON.parse(open(url).read)
      @uf = address['uf']
      @city = address['localidade']
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if it's a good practice, because I'm just starting but it worked! Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your form url is the problem. It should be something like this:
`<%= form_tag uf_search_products_path, method: :get do %>`

and make sure you have added `get :uf_search` inside the products collection routes.